# Blank / Empty Search Form field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have set up a search form for my database.  When I search and results are found a message is echoed below the search form. For instance, 10 records found, 0 records found.

How can I get that message to disappear if the search form field is blank/empty. Currently it displays **15 records found** for a blank/empty search field.  Which is all the database records.

Thanks for any help.

**Form:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search_box" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['search_box'])) echo $_POST['search_box']; ?>" placeholder="Search here ..."/>
    <input value="Search" name="search" type="submit" /><br>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0){
            echo $count . " Records Found";
        }if($count == 0){
            echo "0 Records Found";
        }if($count == ""){
            echo "";
        }
        ?>
```

**Query:**

```
//Retrieve the practice posts from the database table
$query = "SELECT * FROM practice";

//check if search... button clicked, if so query fields
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search_term = trim($_POST['search_box']);
    $query .= " WHERE title = '{$search_term}'";
    $query .= " or subject LIKE '%{$search_term}%'";}
```

Comment: There might be an error in your query, please post it here

Comment: Paste your query it must be return $count = 15

Comment: when search field is empty(no where clause), query is fetching all the records, so 15.

Comment: may be something wrong with your search query...please post that query .

Comment: Thanks for replies so far, just added the query code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

//Retrieve the practice posts from the database table
$query = "SELECT * FROM practice";

//check if search... button clicked, if so query fields
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search_term = trim($_POST['search_box']);
    $query .= " WHERE title = '{$search_term}'";
    $query .= " or subject LIKE '%{$search_term}%'";

   //execute your query
    $result = $dbconnect->query($query);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count > 0){
       echo $count . " Records Found";
    }
    if($count == 0){
       echo "0 Records Found";
    }
}
else {
   // it is mean your search box value($_POST['search']) is empty, so it will echo null value 
   echo $_POST['search'];
}
?>
```

please try, hope will save your day :D

Comment: Nice 1, angvee - worked, thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace PHP code with these one :-

```
<?php
           if(isset($_REQUEST['search_box'])){
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        } else {
         $count = '';
        }
        if($count > 0){
            echo $count . " Records Found";
        }if($count == 0){
            echo "0 Records Found";
        }if($count == ""){
            echo "";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: `search_box` will always be posted, he will need to also check if its `empty()`

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in the post method

```
 if ((isset($_POST['search_box'])) && ($_POST['search_box']!=""))
{

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count > 0){
        echo $count . " Records Found";
    }if($count == 0){
        echo "0 Records Found";
    }if($count == ""){
        echo "";
    }
}
```

Comment: [same comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846292/blank-empty-search-form-field#comment65057505_38846376)

Comment: looks fine. next time try using simplified [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in future. :)